# Replacement of NAs for in the variable?

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

Good evening,

I have dataset where there is one variable which is Gender with missing data. Could anyone please help me how could i replace these NAs using R Packages. I have tried the "Mice" package however it does not replace the NAs and its still exist in data under gender column. I have provide the sample data below with my codes. Thanks in advance for the support.

[Dataset sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jtne.jpg)

R- codes used:
[Used R-codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVD7A.jpg)

Regards,
Kumar

Comment: ould you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

That's too much code. You can try imputing the missing data with either of method="rf" or method="cart" although in my experience the cart method seems to be more accurate. 
 You could also use the preprocess function and either of medianImpute or knnImpute as it gives pretty good results for this kind of imputation.
Example with mice:

```
test_imp<-mice(df,m=5,method="cart",printFlag=F)
 test_imputed<-complete(test_imp,3)#Selects third imputation
```

Example with preprocess

```
test_1<-preprocess(testdf,"medianImpute")
test_imputed<-predict(test_imputed,test_1)
```

Comment: Hi, Good evening, Thank you for the solution however after executing cart method as well i NAs still in variable Gender.Please advise .

Comment: Try "pmm" or "rf". You can see more methods using methods(mice). Good luck!